# How to cope with nested parenthesis in str.extract in pandas?

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-3.7

I have the following piece of code:

```
df['hms'].str.extract('([0-9]{2}\_[0-9]{2}\_[0-9]{2}\_)')
```

Where the string in the column is like: "12_31_31_" (which is actually a timestamp). The code above works, however what I would like to do is redefine the pattern `([0-9]{2}\_[0-9]{2}\_[0-9]{2}\_)`, as `([0-9]{2}\_){3}`. The code would be:

```
display(df['event_id'].str.extract('([0-9]{2}\_){3}'))
```

But the matching would result in `21_` or something similar.

Example code:

```
test = pd.Series(['12_41_15_asds', '41_14_11_adfsag'])
test.str.extract('([0-9]{2}\_){3}')
```

I think the pattern fails, because they only look at the inner parenthesis, however if I need to add an additional parenthesis around everything, I would get two columns. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: What do you want finally? Do you want the date to be extracted?

Comment: Yes, the only thing that I want is to make the pattern more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the double parentheses but make the inner one non-capturing:

```
test.str.extract('((?:\d{2}\_){3})')
```

where the `(?: ... )` marks a non-capturing group.